# How to make Junit test run all tests instead of stopping at first failture

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, maven, junit

How to make Junit test run all unit tests instead of stopping at first failure?
Currently, there are 48 tests in a test file, but when 1 test fails, the tests after that failing test are not run.

I am using latest Eclipse Luna, JDK 8, with maven. Is there a way to adjust the settings so that I could run all the tests and see the failed one**s**?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How are you running the tests?

Comment: @DaveNewton : Testfile -> right click -> Run as -> Junit Test.

Comment: Right-clicking in *what*? Are you in an IDE? Perhaps that information would be useful to include in the question.

Comment: @DaveNewton : Thanks for the reply. I am using Eclipse, JDK8

Comment: That edit doesn't make sense a lot. "..., luna, Eclipse, ...". Shouldn't it be "Eclipse Luna"?

Comment: @TomášZíma : modified. Thanks for pointing that out. Can you take a look to see if you have any ideas now?

Comment: Well, my Eclipse always runs all unit tests and doesn't stop after first failure. I'm trying to figure out if there's some config for that.

Comment: AFAIK maven surefire plugin must have such setting. Kind of 'fail-fast'. Dig for it in pom.xml files.

Comment: If all your assertions are in a single test method (yuck) have a look at AssertJ's soft assertions (or, better, split into separate test cases), if `@Test`-annotated methods don't run after an earlier failure fix Eclipse config because that's not the default behaviour.

Answer (score -2):

To avoid test failure,you should make your test independent if you can.Because it totally depends on your system whether to make make dependent or independent.
Other thing you can do is to avoid assert.Apply if else to continue test execution even test fails and write all the logs in a log file to analyze test result.
You have 48 test in your test file try to make their group,TestNg provide support for this.

Comment: What does "avoid assert" mean exactly?

Comment: Avoid assert means implement decision making statement like if else so that if condition fails ,test execution should be continued because assert stops the execution if test fails.